# Does Xamarin support certificate revocation list (CRL) checks in X509Chain?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I've been trying to validate an X509Chain in Xamarin using a custom X509ChainPolicy with default revocation mode and flag `X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain`. During testing, regardless of whether the chain's leaf certificate (a) did not include CRL information, (b) did include CRL information and was not revoked and (c) did include CRL information and was revoked, the result returned was always `X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown`.

Sample code:

```
X509Certificate cert = // ...
X509Chain originalChain = // ...
var customChainPolicy = new X509ChainPolicy();
customChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain;

foreach (var certificate in originalChain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore)
{
  customChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(certificate);
}

var certificateChain = new X509Chain();
certificateChain.ChainPolicy = customChainPolicy;

var successful = certificateChain.Build(new X509Certificate2(cert));
```

The above code will always return `X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown` in `certificateChain.ChainStatus`. Am I missing something?

Comment: This might best be tracked in a bug report against the platform you are testing with on bugzilla https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/. If possible, attach a sample project to the report as well. Thanks!

Comment: @therealjohn, thanks for the heads-up! I'll surely do that but I first wanted to check whether I'm making any wrong assumptions / mistakes here. Do you happen to know that this is buggy / not implemented in Xamarin or was your comment more a general remark?

Comment: I don't know the answer. A bug report and investigation might be the quickest way to yield if this is an issue or not. It might be specific to mono since this is not Xamarin.iOS/Android specific.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I am facing the same problem!

Comment: No, I never found a solution and stopped investigating at some point in time. I have also never checked whether things have changed since back in 2017.